# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

i'm trying to have a socket working on my sever

here is my app.js file

```
 console.log('app.js says hi');
 var express = require('express');  
 var app = express();  
 var server = require('http').createServer(app);  
 var io = require('socket.io')(server);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));  
app.get('/', function(req, res,next) {  
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
server.listen(4200);
```

and my index.html file

```
     <!doctype html>  
     <html lang="en">  
     <head>

    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <div id="future"></div>
    <form id="form" id="chat_form">
        <input id="chat_input" type="text">
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="socket.io.js"></script>    
    <script>  
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4200');
socket.on('connect', function(data) {
    socket.emit('join', 'Hello World from client');
 });
</script>        
</body>
</html>
```

and in the console log I get this error:
`GET http://localhost:4200/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LsOF2yq net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: Nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to. This is rather basic.

Comment: how can i fix this

Comment: You can fix it by, err, ensuring that something is listening at the IP:port you are trying to connect to. This is also rather basic.

Comment: i'm really new to this could you be more specific how to that something is listening at the IP:port you i'm trying to connect to

Comment: Your alleged server should be listening at the alleged port. If you don't know how to ensure that, you aren't competent to complete this assignment, and your question is too broad for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found it

replace this line

var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4200');

with

var socket = io.connect('http://yourdomain.com:4200');